# php connect and show mysql table - LAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, server, lamp

Im running a LAMP server and im trying to show on the webpage the table of my database

This is my php script

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "none";
$dbname = "chegada";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{echo "OK!";}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

And the webpage shows this

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 17
>
> OK!
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()
>   in /var/www/html/index.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 22

can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Mixing mysqli with mysql

Comment: Do not use deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use MySQLi / PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; // maybe this should be an empty string if you dont have password setup
$dbname = "chegada";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // this should be mysqli_query
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{echo "OK!";}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
    exit;
} else {
    $res = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
    var_dump($res);
}
```

Comment: thank you but i only get OK! on the page, still not printing the table, i think i was getting the 1º error because when i tryed to login in mysql it gave me ERROR 2002 (...) @erwan

Comment: i edited the code so that the $res variable should contain what you expect,

Comment: i have in the connect.php this:

$servername = "127.0.0.1";

$username = "root";

$password = "none";

$dbname = "chegada";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, 

$dbname); // this should be mysqli_query

if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}

And got the query ion the index.php
And it still not showing

Answer (score 0):

**Use mysqli_query**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I supect that you have a default local mysql, in which case password "none" is an empty string. Literally no password, not the word "none". You need:

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "chegada";
```

Your second bug is caused by the fact you've started off in mysqli_ but then reverted to mysql_ half way down.